# Make dots between numbers in php

Tags: php

I would like to make dots between my total value.

If i have 425000 i would like it to show as 425.000

Is there a function in php that implodes dots for numbers or how can i do this then?

Comment: What is the background of this - what kind of a value is 425000? Is it a large number that you want to show in the european format?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) for this:

```
$number =  425000;
echo number_format( $number, 0, '', '.' );
```

The above example means: format the number, using `0` decimal places, an empty string as the decimal point (as we're not using decimal places anyway), and use `.` as the thousands separator.

Unless of course I misunderstood your intent, and you want to format the number as a number with 3 decimal places:

```
$number =  425000;
echo number_format( $number, 3, '.', '' );
```

The above example means: format the number, using `3` decimal places, `.` as the decimal point (default), and an empty string as the thousands separator (defaults to `,`).

If the default thousands separator is good enough for you, you can just use <sup>1</sup>:

```
$number =  425000;
echo number_format( $number, 3 );
```

---

<sub>1) Mind you: `number_format` accepts either 1, 2 or 4 parameters, not 3.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

I guess you're looking for the [`number_format`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) function.